# session variable not recognizable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

```
string Landcode = Session("landcode");
```

gives a fault message:

Error   2   The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

I see the word session in the intellisense. And the session variable is declared in the global.asax.

```
 void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        string landcode = Request["strLandCode"];
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you trying to access the Session object from?

The code for getting the Session value would be (you would also want to check it is not null before calling .ToString():

```
  string landcode = Session["landcode"].ToString();
```

The Request object and Session object are not the same object too. You would have to do the following to add landcode to the Session:

```
Session["landcode"] = strLandCode;
```

Comment: i have a aspx page (default.aspx) with javascript. In the javascript part there is an ajax call that send the countrycode to the global.asax ($.post("Global.asax", { strLandCode: LandCode });)  thats way i wrote string landcode = Request["strlandcode"]

Comment: I debugged it again, and i think i know where it is not working  (string strLandcode = Request["strLandCode"];) strLandCode is still null

Answer (score 1):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Session["landcode"]`

Session is some kind of dictionary and so you index into it with `[]` rather than use a method call ie `()`

And in C# you also have to cast each object so when getting string object precede with `(string)`, when getting an int precede with `(int)` etc...

Comment: i tried this as well , and it seems that string Landcode ( so the first one) doesn't get filled with the session variable. I changed the second code a bit to string landcode = "BE". But string Landcode is still null.

Answer (score -1):

This is How to use session in ASP.NET and C#

```
//This how to add value in session "ID" Is the name of the session and "1" is the value
Session.Add("ID", 1);
//How to retrieve the value which is in the Session 
int ID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["ID"]);
//write session Value
Response.Write(ID.ToString());
```

Please Try it and tell us the result

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvoting!!